# Meaning of "Feminism is BAY"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In S05E04 of [BoJack Horseman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8266820/?ref_=ttep_ep4) TV-series BoJack appeared in a "Feminism is BAY" t-shirt, emphasizing his pro-feminist attitude. I don't know for sure whether it's the creators of the show who came up with that idea or it's a well-known phrase. Such t-shirts are now available for purchase online.
Could someone explain the original meaning of the phrase, if there is one? Apart from bay being a horse-themed play of words.

Comment: What research have you done on this?  A simple google search could yield a lot of insight into bae/bay.

Comment: Not to say the current answers are wrong, but it might simply be that the joke in the spelling is that "bay" can be  [a reddish-brown animal, especially a horse having a black mane and tail](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bay),. Occam's razor, folks.

Comment: @Robusto I'm rooting for a broad inlet of the sea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bay" (also "bae") is a slang term that is a shortened form of  "baby", a term of endearment as in, "She's my baby." Over time, the term also came to be used to express that something is cool. This second use isn't very popular or accepted in popular culture, though, so BoJack Horseman (because it is comedy) is using the term presumably because the writers wanted to show that BoJack doesn't even understand feminism (since "bay" in it's more popular context almost always refers to a woman by her relationship to a man).

Answer (score 0):

No.  Half of the joke is that the word he meant to use was "bae", and not "bay."  Bae means "Before Anyone Else" and is a term of endearment (though certainly not a feminist one).

"Bay" in this context means "I heard a word somewhere and thought it was hip so decided to to use it, but I have no idea what I'm doing and didn't bother to look it up first"  The fact that other people have now managed to do the same has just perpetuated the punchline to this slow rolling joke.  The fact that others have done so specifically because they saw this on Bojack, didn't get it, and then imitated him is more like a meta-punchline.

Yes, it's Bojack's tone def attempt to associate himself with hipness and feminism with an entirely absurd juxtaposition... but the second half of the joke is that he can't even manage to do that right.